# Передать функцию в переменной

Tags: javascript, node.js, html2canvas, playwright

Запускаю браузер с помощью playwright, потом хочу сделать скриншот элемента с помощью html2canvas.
В примере пишу только все связанное с html2canvas и его передачей в браузер playwright

```
const { default: html2canvas } = require("html2canvas");
const screenshot = await page.evaluate((html2canvas) => {
           var x = html2canvas(document.getElementById(`id("fear-and-greed-dial")`)).then(function(canvas) {
              canvas.toDataURL();              
              document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(my_screen);
                var imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL ("image / png"); 
                return imgUrl;
        } );
        return x;
        });
```

Вылетает с ошибкой *html2canvas is not a function*. Но как передать функцию?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На какую именно строку ругается?

Comment: @SwaD ругается на вторую по счету, говорит, что html2canvas is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый, попробовать передать функцию в качестве зависимости

```
const { default: html2canvas } = require("html2canvas");

const screenshot = await page.evaluate(async (html2canvas) => {
  var x;
  await html2canvas(document.getElementById(`id("fear-and-greed-dial")`)).then(function(canvas) {
    canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(my_screen);
    var imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL ("image / png");
    //return imgUrl;
    x = imgUrl;
  } );
  return x;
}, html2canvas);
```

Если не сработает, то отказаться от зависимости и просто использовать html2canvas внутри `page.evaluate`

Так же обратите внимание, что из .then() return не сработает и html2canvas асинхронная функция

```
const { default: html2canvas } = require("html2canvas");

const screenshot = await page.evaluate(async () => {
  var x;
  await html2canvas(document.getElementById(`id("fear-and-greed-dial")`)).then(function(canvas) {
    canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(my_screen);
    var imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL ("image / png");
    //return imgUrl;
    x = imgUrl;
  } );
  return x;
});
```

Comment: и в первом и во втором случае ошибка: **html2canvas is not defined**
я попробовал все содержимое файла html2canvas.js загнать в переменную внутри page.evaluate. но получаю **html2canvas is not a function**
функция в яваскрипт может быть переменной, но переменная не может быть функцией?

Comment: Переменная может быть функцией. Кстати, попробуйте заменить импорт const html2canvas = require("html2canvas")

Comment: заменил, **function is not defined**

да, нашел информацию - переменная может стать функцией
const html2canvas = new Function(html2canv); //в последней переменной весь код


но эта библиотека содержит несколько функций, и передавать ее целиком похоже было тупиковым путем. в данном случае пишет **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')**


сам код библиотеки обфусцирован.


наверное, надо написать разработчикам playwright, задача оказалась нетривиальной

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась через внутренний API сайта, к тому же playwright умеет делать скриншот элемента